# Why does riot.js break css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, riot.js

In  order to learn riot.js I started from well-known bootstrap navbar example. Then I added my custom tag using riot.js:

```
<script type="riot/tag">
  <menu-item>
    <li><a href={this.href}><yield/></a></li>
    this.href = opts.href
  </menu-item>
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/riot@2.2(riot.min.js+compiler.min.js)"></script>
<script>
  riot.mount('*')
</script>
```

Finally I tried to use my new tag, replacing

```
<li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
```

by

```
<menu-item href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</menu-item>
```

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/0hp9pwpu/1/) is broken. Why? (original non-broken example can be found here: jsfiddle.net/0hp9pwpu)

Answer (score 5):

Your riot tag markup is inserted into your riot tag i.e. what happens is

```
ul
    li
```

from your working example is actually

```
ul 
    menu-item
         li
```

in your non-working example. Since bootstrap styles the navigation items expecting a certain hierarchy, your result is broken.

This was raised as an issue (https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/295) and closed using https://github.com/riot/riot/pull/569 i.e. instead of using the riot tags directly there is an option to add the riot tag as an attribute. So something like

```
<li riot-tag="menu-item" href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</li>
```

Admittedly, it is not as semantic

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/86khqhwu/

Comment: Thank you. Albeit I don't like that riot-tag. :(

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is not adapted for use with Riot.js

Your resulted html is :

```
<menu-item href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">
    <li>
        <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a>
    </li>
</menu-item>
```

Bootstrap css is broken ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not so elegant, but in riot 2.3.13 I'm using something like this in a .tag file:

```
<menu-bar>
  <ul list="<yield/>">
    <li each={ item in items }>
      <a href="http://localhost/pages/{ item }.html">{ titles[item] }</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    this.titles = {
      inventario: 'Inventario',
      resguardos: 'Resguardos',
      catalogos:  'Catálogos',
      reportes:   'Reportes',
      configurar: 'Configurar',
      utilidades: 'Utilidades'
    }
    this.items = null

    this.on('mount', function () {
      var el = this.root.querySelector('ul')
      this.items = el.getAttribute('list').trim().split(/,\s?/)
      el.removeAttribute('list')
      this.update()
    })
  </script>
</menu-bar>
```

Now, in the HTML page:

```
<menu-bar>
  inventario,resguardos,catalogos,reportes
</menu-bar>
```

Works.